# Export data from Excel to an existing list in SharePoint Server 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, export

What is the best method in SharePoint to export data from Excel to an existing list in SharePoint Server 2016?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key point in your question is importing excel data to an **existing** list! not to a new list.

**In this case,** the `Import Spreadsheet` functionality is not an option for your requirements.

---

**So let's explore What're the available workarounds that match your requirements?**

- If the Excel dataset size is a `little bit`, so you can add the data **manually** by creating `Datasheet view` then switch your list view to `Datasheet view` to View data in an `editable spreadsheet format` that is convenient for **bulk** editing and quick customization.
- If the Excel dataset size is `big`, so try to create a windows application that read data from excel sheet and add it to a specific list. as the following:

  - [Read Excel File In C# WinForm to Dataset](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/read-excel-file-in-c-sharp-winform/)
  - Loop for the Excel Data.
  - [Upload Excel data into SharePoint List using C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/code/1522/upload-excel-data-into-sharepoint-list-using-c-sharp.aspx)

> **Note:** you can customize the windows application to run periodically through the `Task Schedule`.

Answer (score 1):

That's right, because this is an existing SharePoint List, it's not as easy as using the import spreadsheet option, sadly.

Another way to do it is by manually copying and pasting from Excel to the SharePoint List in edit list view.

First ensure your column order in Excel matches up with the order as they appear in the SharePoint List View (you could also create a new View and call it "Importing" and choose & order the columns as required to match the Excel file).

To start the manual import:

1) Either choose "**edit this list**" or choose from the Ribbon: **List** > **Quick edit**, to get in to bulk-editing mode.
2) Select all data from the Excel Spreadsheet and Paste in to the SharePoint Online.

If you have more than 100 entries, it's recommended you do only 100 lines at a time or so, as the system will take some time to save them back to the server. I've been able to successfully paste about 300-400 at a time.

Also note: If you have required fields, numerical columns or drop downs (choice menu), ensure the imported data matches the requirement for the fields prior to pasting.

*[Hope this helps! I'm new here, and its my first answer. So if I've missed any thing please let me know..]*

Answer (score 0):

If you have Access on your machine you can use it to open the SharePoint List and copy-paste the content what you need.

I've just tested this approach using SharePoint Online so it should work with SharePoint 2016 as well.